# filter length of time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, data-warehouse

I need to calculate the time that is between 8AM and 10PM. Other time I dont need.
and now I do this by excel, and I want to do automate the process

I have the following table, events

```
start_date         |     end_date          | duration_REAL | duration_08AM_a_10PM
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
08:00AM 20-05-2014 | 02:00 PM 20-05-2014   | 06:00         |     06:00
04:00AM 20-05-2014 | 06:00 AM 20-05-2014   | 02:00         |     00:00
08:00AM 20-05-2014 | 10:00 PM 20-05-2014   | 14:00         |     14:00
04:00AM 20-05-2014 | 11:00 PM 20-05-2014   | 19:00         |     14:00
04:00AM 20-05-2014 | 04:00 PM 21-05-2014   | 36:00         |     24:00
```

DATE = TIME DAY-MM-YY

What I have is the real duration, but, I want to the duration for the event between 8AM and 10PM.

For example,

- If my event starts today at 4 AM and ends today at 5 AM in the morning, the duration of this event considering 8AM-10PM would be 00hs.
- If my event starts today at 4 AM and ends today as 2PM, the duration of this event considering 8AM-10PM would be 6 hours.
- If my event starts today at 2 PM and ends the following day at 2PM, the duration of 8 to 22 would be 14 hours.

Comment: now in english and tagged, I use mysql...

Comment: I only receive negative reputation :( I'l wait good answers :D

Comment: Isn't the real duration between `04:00AM 20-05-2014` and `04:00 PM 20-05-2014` 12 hours?

Comment: You may find this similar sql-server question helpful: [Calculate time difference (only working hours) in minutes between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3296923/622391)

Comment: simon! you'r right! 4 PM is the next day, now I edited! thanks.. I am cheking the other post... tomorrow I will try

Comment: I tried the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296923/calculate-time-difference-only-working-hours-in-minutes-between-two-dates and this is very good, is a little slow but this work man! thanks all of you!

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer... thanks guys!

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `BD`.`func_duration`(fecha_ini DATETIME, fecha_fin DATETIME)
RETURNS FLOAT 
BEGIN
DECLARE recorte FLOAT;
SET recorte = -1;

WHILE (fecha_ini <= fecha_fin) DO
    IF (HOUR(fecha_ini) >= 6 AND HOUR(fecha_ini) <= 21) THEN

        SET recorte = recorte + 1;
    END IF;
    SET fecha_ini = DATE_ADD(fecha_ini, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);
END WHILE;
RETURN recorte;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```